# React-native: How do I allow composite ListViews to spread out as long as their content requires?

Tags: css, listview, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a composite ListView, which is essentially a primary ListView with 3 sub-ListViews rendered as each "row" of the primary listview. The layout looks like this:

[image]

The code is something like this:

```
renderRow = (rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => {
    const ds =  new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
        sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
    });
    console.log("rendering row"+rowData+"\n"+"sectionID"+sectionID+"rowID"+rowID);
    nameList = this.eventsToNameListMap[sectionID];
    return (
            <ListView 
                  enableEmptySections={true}
                  dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(nameList[rowID])}
                  renderRow={this.renderInternalRow}
                  renderSectionHeader={ (sectionData,sectionID) => {
                        return <Text style = {styles.sectionHeader}>{rowID}</Text> 
                    }
                  }
              />
    );
}

renderInternalRow = (rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => {
    console.log("rendering internal  row"+rowData+"\n"+"sectionID"+sectionID+"rowID"+rowID);
    return (
        <Text>{rowData}</Text>
    );
}

render(){
    return (
        <View>
            <ListView style = {styles.listView}
                  enableEmptySections={true}
                  dataSource={ this.state.dataSource}
                  renderRow={this.renderRow}
                  renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
              />
        </View>
    );
}
```

where the renderRow of the primary ListView renders another ListView as its row.
However, the problem is that each sub-ListView becomes evenly spaced out within each "row" of the primary ListView, causing each sub-ListView to become internally scrollable so that it can fit the fixed width. I want each sub-ListView to space out as much as they need according to the length of their content. How do I achieve this with styles? My current configuration has no styles applied.

Comment: I think you are better with a single ListView and modyfing your render() methods so that the visual effect achieved is the same. Is there any specific motivation to have separate/nested ListViews? To me, it generally makes sense only when the direction of scroll changes.

Comment: The advantage I see for having nested list views is that I only need a single dictionary to represent all the data.(A primary dictionary to map a string to a second dictionary, which maps a section name(A,B or C) to an array of names) If I use a single list view, it is still possible but I would have to append the section names (A,B,C) to the list of names which is quite messy. Furthermore, I would need the section name to have a different style from the names themselves,which would be quite unachievable if both the section names and the names themselves are in the same array.

Comment: Well, in this case, you could always make `section` an object with title (letter) and parentSectionTitle (for instance), so you can check what exactly is that and decide how to render section header based on some properties and their values. I'd say that a mapped single dictionary (even with a bit messy set up) is still better then nested ListViews given that it only requires you to provide a dataSet in a correct format and the rest will be layed out properly (it will also work nicely with `onEndReached` callbacks and be able to apply some optimisations once to all rows)